# Index was outside the bounds of the array error occur when insert data to a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to insert text file data to `sql` server database,here is my sample code,when i execute this, only first line of the text file `(10,sac,10 hung vuong)` saved to the database and this error is occur

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>   Index was outside the
>   bounds of the array.

**sample text file**

```
10,sac,10 hung vuong

11,mad,11 Hung call

22,wick,22 Hung poll
```

here is my code

```
string line;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=texttodb;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"E:\a.txt"))
        {
            while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] fields = line.Split(',');

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblUser(id, name, address) VALUES (@id, @name, @address)", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", fields[0].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", fields[1].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", fields[2].ToString());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if this is the exact text file

```
10,sac,10 hung vuong

11,mad,11 Hung call

22,wick,22 Hung poll
```

You have blank lines between each data line. Edit the file to:

```
10,sac,10 hung vuong    
11,mad,11 Hung call    
22,wick,22 Hung poll
```

Or put a conditional

```
 if (line.Length > 0) {
      string[] fields = line.Split(',');
      ....
 }
```

Comment: The Length of the "fields" string array may by still be something else than 3 even if the Length of the line is greater than 0 though. That's why I suggested checking the actual length of the array before trying to access the strings in it.

Comment: @mm8 You are right, but number of fields is a different validation *(and OP also should include it)*. But you could check a lot of other things too, like first field must be integer, etc. But for the `'blank line'` validation that should happen before the split. Doesn't make sense do the split of empty string.

Comment: Sure :) There is nothing wrong with your answer. It was just a note, mainly for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you skip any blank lines:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
    if(fields.Length == 3) //<--
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblUser(id, name, address) VALUES (@id, @name, @address)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", fields[0].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", fields[1].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", fields[2].ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```